# If he has a problem with the reservation, what is the probability that he stays in hotel B?

Tags: probability

My homework problem:

Mr. Smith stays at hotel A $50\%$ of the time in his frequent trips to Toronto, at hotel B $30\%$ of the time, and at hotel C $20\%$ of the time. He has some problems with the reservation $3\%$ of the time at hotel A, $6\%$ of the time at hotel B, and $10\%$ of the time at hotel C. Suppose he travels to Toronto next week.

(a) Find the probability that he stays at hotel A and has a problem with the reservation.

$$0.03 \cdot 0.5 = 0.015$$

(b) If he has a problem with the reservation, what is the probability that he stays in hotel B?

$$0.06 \cdot 0.3 = 0.018$$

I thought I was doing the problem correctly, but the steps for my solutions seem oddly simple for a question that is worth a notable amount of marks, particularly b). I was wondering if someone could confirm whether or not I solved these questions correctly? Is there another way to solve these problems with one of the probability formulas or through the use of permutations rather than just simple multiplication?

Comment: Have you seen Bayes' rule?

Comment: I looked up the formula, I don't think I'm familiar with that rule.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to part (a) is correct.

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be the events that he stays at hotel $A$, $B$, and $C$ respectively.  Let $P$ be the event that he has a problem with the reservation.  In part (b), you computed the probability that he has a problem with the reservation and stays at hotel $B$.
$$\Pr(P \cap B) = \Pr(P \mid B)\Pr(B) = 0.06 \cdot 0.3 = 0.018$$
What you need to compute is the probability that he stays at hotel B given that he has a problem with the reservation.  That means your sample space consists of all events in which he has a problem with the reservation, so the event you need to compute is 
$$\Pr(B \mid P) = \frac{\Pr(P \cap B)}{\Pr(P)}$$
The probability that he has a problem with the reservation is 
$$\Pr(P) = \Pr(P \cap A) + \Pr(P \cap B) + \Pr(P \cap C)$$
I will leave it to you to complete the calculation.